# How to use libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-studio

I'm trying to get the libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar imported to my project in Android Studio. First I added it using the Project Structure which corrected any red lines when trying to use EasyTracker. But when I compiled it resulted with errors and the build failed.

```
Gradle: package com.google.analytics.tracking.android does not exist
Gradle: cannot find symbol variable EasyTracker
Gradle: cannot find symbol variable EasyTracker
```

I'm using the lib like this:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
```

What can I do to make this work? Thanks

Comment: I was trying to resurrect a 1 yr old app that was running V2, but it kept crashing. I ended up removing al V2 code and no it doesn't crash so I can implement a decent Google Analytics V4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to reference the jar in the build.gradle, something like this:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
```

`libs` in this case being the libs dir in your project, above `src`

Comment: In more recent versions of Android Studio, the Project Structure dialog will now do the right thing and add the correct dependencies to your build.gradle file.

Comment: can you clarify the actual path of that file? you say 'libs in this case' but there's no 'libs' in your example. Do you mean 'theres a folder called libs at the same level as src,build.gradle,build etc?

Comment: I added the libs/ dir back to the example

Comment: I think `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` is a more convenient option. Gradle will link to your project every library you put in the libs folder.

Comment: Yeah and when I add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' I get the duplicate crap error.

Comment: Please how can I add libgoogleAnalytics whitout using its .jar. I mean just like complie 'com.example...' (as a package with its version)?